# Modification with ASTRewrite not recursive

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am using ASTRewrite to convert this:

```
new Targect1().asd(a);
```

Into this:

```
Targect1 temp1 = new Targect1();
temp1.asd(a);
```

This is my code:

```
String temp_identifier = getNextVariableId();
VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = node.getAST().newVariableDeclarationFragment();
fragment.setName(node.getAST().newSimpleName(temp_identifier));
ClassInstanceCreation creation = (ClassInstanceCreation)rewrite.createCopyTarget(node.getExpression()));
fragment.setInitializer(creation);
VariableDeclarationStatement previous_declaration = node.getAST().newVariableDeclarationStatement(fragment);
rewrite.replace(node, previous_declaration,null);
```

It is not finished but when check the value of fragment it get the methoddeclaration inside, but nothing about the type. When I inspect it shows:

```
temp1 = new MISSING()
```

Comment: The shown code is inside: public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node)

Answer (score 0):

`ASTRewrite.createCopyTarget(...)` creates only a placeholder node. The actual copy of the expression is not created until you call `ASTRewrite.rewriteAST()`. This is why you see `new MISSING()` when you inspect `fragment`.

If you want to force an immediate copy then you have to use `ASTNode.copySubtree(AST target, ASTNode node)`.